# Chronicle Queue MethodReader stops reading

Tags: chronicle-queue

Chronicle Queue MethodReader suddenly stops reading without any error, the busy loop keeps going but readOne is false beyond that point.The only option is to recreate methodReader, then it works normally.

The occurrence is rare and random, and hard to reproduce.

Wonder if anyone else came across such or if it’s specific to chronic queue version we using i.e. 5.22.18.